# Find value in XML

Tags: ruby

I have a value in which I store XML.

I want to search for this value into the XML:

```
<transaction_type>authorize</transaction_type>

<transaction_type>authorize3d</transaction_type>
```

If there is a value "3d" I want to edit the XML file. If not I want to send it.

```
def web_request(request_body)

    //Search here in request body for 3d value
    if request_body.include? "3d"
     puts "String include '3d'"
    else
     puts "String does not include '3d'"
    end

    .........
    request_body
  end
```

How I can implement this properly?

Comment: Maybe nokogiri? http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html

Comment: How do you receive the XML before you store it?

Answer (score 0):

Use regexp to find a node with `3d` text:

```
if request_body =~ /<transaction_type>.*?3d<\/transaction_type>/
```

Too you can use Nokogiri to parse xml and find a node with this value but in your case, it's overhead.